# "IOError: Shuffle read failed: UNKNOWN: Stream removed" in Google Dataflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow

My Google Dataflow pipeline has recently starting throwing many `IOError` exceptions (~50 before it terminates). Ideally, the dataflow script will iterate through 130 million records from BigQuery, computing then outputting a csv file to google cloud storage. When I run the dataflow on an input of this size, it fails, throwing the exception below. However, when I run the dataflow on a smaller input of ~5 million records, not a single exception is thrown and the script completes as intended.

Currently, my dataflow configuration deploys 100 `n1-standard-1` compute engines, running `apache_beam==2.1.1`.

Any help would be much appreciated. I don't understand why this `IOError` is being raised. Does anyone understand what this traceback is telling me? Thank you!

```
(7bdef4cd15d44c08): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 582, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 166, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 49, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3605)
    def start(self):
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 50, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3509)
    with self.scoped_start_state:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 65, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3424)
    with self.shuffle_source.reader() as reader:
  File "dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.py", line 67, in dataflow_worker.shuffle_operations.GroupedShuffleReadOperation.start (dataflow_worker/shuffle_operations.c:3340)
    for key_values in reader:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 406, in __iter__
    for entry in entries_iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 248, in next
    return next(self.iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/shuffle.py", line 206, in __iter__
    chunk, next_position = self.reader.Read(start_position, end_position)
  File "third_party/windmill/shuffle/python/shuffle_client.pyx", line 84, in shuffle_client.PyShuffleReader.Read
IOError: Shuffle read failed: UNKNOWN: Stream removed  talking to transform-warehouse-to-de-11201527-b7d9-harness-lxq2:12346
```

Comment: Do you have job_id for the job? It helps with looking into more details on errors.

Comment: @RaghuAngadi The job_id is `2017-11-20_19_38_07-12190089098856929862`. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running on bigger machines?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki I have not. Would you recommend increasing the amount of RAM or HDD space? Thanks.

Comment: Try both and see what happens

Comment: @MarcinZablocki Thank you for your help. I doubled the RAM from 3.5gb to 7gb and it all worked properly.